# Calling static Java methods in the ScriptEngine's environment/context

Tags: java, jruby

I can write scripts which run in a closed-source Java app. The scripts have acces to the application's static API.

The following script asks the Static API where the mouse is positioned on the Java App window:

```
public class JavaScript extends Script {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(General.getMousePos());
    }
}
```

However this does not work (API crashes with NullPointerException):

```
public class JavaScript extends Script {
    public void run() {
        ScriptEngineManager m = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine rubyEngine = m.getEngineByName("jruby");
        rubyEngine.eval("puts General.getRealMousePos()");
    }
}
```

Because of `General.respond_to? "getRealMousePos" == true` I think that the Ruby code is talking with a different instance of the API that is not initialised by the application.

Is it possible to pass objects from Java to Ruby or call methods from the environment/context where the ScriptEngine object is running? I only found strings (setContext/setAttrib)

Comment: I note that you use `getMousePos` in Java but `getRealMousePos` in Ruby. Could you make them match up, and also run the Java code immediately before the Ruby code (as I did in my example). Also, please amend your question with the exception trace, in case it has anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your application is doing something very crazy, but I threw together a quick test that seems to show that the scripting container uses the same static data:

**com/test/Static.java**

```
package com.test;

public class Static {
    private static long init;

    static {
        init = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try {
            // If this is run a second time, make sure it's different.
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // LOL
        }
    }

    public static long getInitTime() {
        return init;
    }
}
```

**Main.java**

```
import javax.script.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        ScriptEngineManager m = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine rubyEngine = m.getEngineByName("jruby");

        System.out.println("Java time: " + com.test.Static.getInitTime());
        rubyEngine.eval("puts \"Ruby time: #{com.test.Static.init_time}\"");
    }
}
```

**Run as**

```
javac -cp . *java com/test/*java
jar -cf static.jar com/
java -cp jruby.jar:. Main
```

**Output**

```
Java time: 1388707668166
Ruby time: 1388707668166
```

Comment: This actually worked for the API's "General" class, but sadly not all.

Comment: I'm not following what you mean... what exactly worked, and what exactly does not work (how does it fail, etc.)?

Comment: The API is poorly written, some classes are static, some are just final, etc...
I managed to get the classes I need by casting them to a "Class" and "Method" Objects and then pass them to JRuby through the context.setAttribute method